# PHP, given two inputs, make a link

Tags: php

I want to make a we page with 2 inputs. The user enters "John" and "Smith" into the inputs and clicks submit.

I want the submit to act like a link that looks like http://www.example.com/Smith/John

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you mean "act like a link"?

Comment: You can redirect the user with `htaccess` you will need to set up a rewrite rule as well...or if `Smith` and `John` are directories it'd work I think.

Comment: It's very possible. Sounds like you want a REST API on the server-side. There are plenty of articles about how to write a RESTful server and there are some frameworks available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a very basic level, you can use the `header()` function and the get/post variables from the form submission like so:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/'.$_POST["input1"].'/'.$_POST["input2"]);
```

This will redirect the user to http://www.example.com/Smith/John upon submission.